# How to display alert if user has't logged in

Tags: php

I have a package page. all users can access it. those who want to order this package must log in first. when the user hasn't logged in and they click the booking button a warning will appear. "You must log in". how can I set like that.
this is the packages
[image: https://i.imgur.com/CSSszbo.png]

Comment: Are you using PHP? Specify the details.

Comment: are you using ajax or direct submit page ?

Comment: yes I using php @Shashidhara

Comment: I'm using ajax @C2486

Comment: which authentication method you are using share all detail you have. ?

Comment: @C2486 I'm sorry I dont know which is it, but it just solved. Thank you very much you have responsed my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is:

While creating links check if the user is logged in or not. If user is logged in then add url of the package, otherwise add a simple javascript code to open popup.

If you are using session then you might need to add something like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){ ?>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Booking</a><?php
}
else{ ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="alert('You must log in')">Booking</a><?php
}
```

Also you would need to add redirection for non logged in users on the package page as well.

Comment: I think this something related to authentication and then display popup

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie, I don't know how to write chek session in javascript, but I make chek session in another file. when I include 'check.php', the alert appear and user hasn't logged in can't access the package page. I want all user can access it but for book user have to log in.
I'm sorry, my english is bad but I hope you understand what I say

Comment: @Aden Updated My Answer

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors and will cause fatal errors if run like this.